# Calculate values before end date

Tags: excel, vba

I'm quite new to VBA, and I'm trying to calculate the values before/equal to the end date requested to the user, but can't seem to figure it out.

| 14/03/2022 (Q1) | 21/03/2022 (R1) |
| --- | --- |
| 08 (Q2) | 10 (R2) |
| 40 (Q3) | 20 (R3) |

my goal is to process each existing row and return the sum on that specific row in column N:N.

so if the user says end date is 21/03 the total value for 2nd row should be 18 and 3rd row 60.

The code should summarize the values corresponding to each A:A column existing cells row. I mean, for the third row, the data will be summarized from the third row bellow the one keeping the reference dates.

Here is my code so far:

```
Sub test()

  Dim WS As Worksheet
 Set WS = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Const EARLIEST = #1/1/2000#
    Dim till As Date
'On Error GoTo Errorhandler
    till = CDate(Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter the date to split the hrs (dd/mm/yyyy):", Type:=2))
    
If till = 0 Then Exit Sub
If till < EARLIEST Then
    MsgBox "You need to insert a valid date dd/mm/yyyy"
    Exit Sub
End If

'need to do more spotchecks as check if date exists in the file

    ActiveSheet.Range("N1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Total until " & till
    
    Dim lr, lc, lc1 As Long
    Dim sum As Long
    lr = Range("Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lc = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    lc1 = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set dates = WS.Range("Q1" & lc1)
    For i = 2 To lr
    If dates.Value <= till Then
    sum = sum + Range("Q2" & lc)
    Range("N" & i).Value = sum
    End If
    Next i

    Columns("N:N").Select
    Selection.Style = "Comma"
    Selection.NumberFormat = _
        "_ * #,##0.0_)_ ;_ * (#,##0.0)_ ;_ * ""-""??_)_ ;_ @_ "
    Selection.NumberFormat = "_ * #,##0_)_ ;_ * (#,##0)_ ;_ * ""-""??_)_ ;_ @_ "
    Columns("N:N").EntireColumn.autofit

'Errorhandler:
'MsgBox "You need to insert a valid date dd/mm/yyyy"
'Resume
End Sub
```

Comment: `Range("Q2" & lc)` doesn't seem right to me. If your last column is 10 for example, this would say `Range("Q210")` which has no correlation to what the rest of the code is trying to do. I think this is where the error lies.

Comment: `Range("N" & i).Value = sum` This could likely be simplified into an excel formula like `=Q2+Q3` and drag it down the column. No need for VBA here.

Comment: `Selection.NumberFormat` is repeated twice on the same column.

Comment: thank you for your help, much appreciated. I need to know the end date, till when the user wants to sum the values. The dates change frequently, so it will not be always the same cells. That's why i'm trying to use VBA. I can't seem to figure out how to calculate only the cells before the end date entered by the user....

Comment: Based on what logic do you say **so if the user says end date is 21/03 the total value for 2nd row should be 18**?

Comment: Do you understand what the following piece of code does: `Set dates = WS.Range("Q1" & lc1)`? If you want the range of "Q:Q" column, you should use `Set dates = WS.Range("Q1:Q" & lc1)`

Comment: `Set dates = WS.Range("Q1" & lc1)` should likely be `Set dates = WS.Range("Q" & i)`

Comment: @FaneDuru - if the user adds 21/03 as end date I want to sum the values of week 14/03 (8) and 21/03 (10), so the total would be 18 - I'm sure the code is not correct but this is what I'm aiming to do. I'm new with VBA so I still do a lot of mistakes :/

Comment: Still not clear for me... What is 14/03? Isn't it fourteenth of March? If so, which to be the involvement of a week? Are there numbers in column "N:N" and you try numbering them until the last day in "Q:Q" is found? If so, you should explain that **in words**. If not, I am still confused, sorry...

Comment: Why not just use `SUMIF` on the worksheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next version:

```
Sub testProcessDate_All()
 Dim WS As Worksheet: Set WS = Worksheets("Sheet1")
 
    Const EARLIEST = #1/1/2000#
    Dim till As Date
    till = CDate(Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter the date to split the hrs (dd/mm/yyyy)" & vbCrLf & _
                                              "or select a cell containing a date in the first row:", Type:=2))

    
    If till = 0 Then Exit Sub
    If till < EARLIEST Then
        MsgBox "You need to insert a valid date dd/mm/yyyy"
        Exit Sub
    End If
     Dim lc1 As Long: lc1 = WS.Cells(1, WS.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
     Dim LatestDate As Date
     LatestDate = WS.Cells(1, lc1).Value
     If till > LatestDate Then MsgBox "The chosen date is larger than last available date...": Exit Sub
    
    'ActiveSheet.Range("N:N").ClearContents 'to be cleared for the next time
    WS.Range("N1").Value = "Total until " & till
    
    Dim lr As Long, sum As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    
    If WS.Range("A2").Value = "" Then MsgBox "No values in A:A to run the code...": Exit Sub
    lr = WS.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row                               'the last row in A:A (for a table...)
   

    For j = 2 To lr
        For i = WS.Range("Q1").Column To lc1
           If CDate(WS.Cells(1, i).Value) <= till Then
              sum = sum + WS.Cells(j, i).Value
           Else
              Exit For
           End If
        Next i
        WS.Range("N" & j).Value = sum: sum = 0
  Next j
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you a lot for your precious help. It is what I'm looking for but the numbers and dates are on the columns instead of rows. So the dates are on Q1 to last column and the numbers from Q2: last column with data. What needs to be changed to achieve that?

Comment: @V F OK. Your question are not so clear, from this point of view and the code does not help in understanding it... If now the iteration should be clear, what about the code line `Range("N" & i).Value = sum`? Do you intend to place the intermediary sum on the N:N column? If so, from which row to start filling it? From the first existing empty row? From the second row?

Comment: @V F Adapted the above code to iterate on rows and return each partial sum to N:N column, **starting from the second row**. Please, test it and send some feedback.

Comment: thank you again for your help, I tried but it does nothing, only the N:N is selected after running. I added a table in my question to make it clearer.

Comment: @V F Does your data looks as you show in the picture? I mean do "(Q1)", "(R1)" exist as we can see them? If so, how the cells in discussion are formatted? If you activate one of these cells containing date and try `Debug.Print Day(activeCell.value)`, what does it return in `Immediate Window`? If not anything confidential, can you share the workbook you try processing? At least the sheet in discussion and the code you use...

Comment: Yes, they exist. They are formatted as date. I have tried for Q1 - 14/03/2022 and it returned 14.
Unfortunately I can't, this is a file from work and the system doesn't even allow me to add a print screen....

Comment: @V F In such circumstances I am not able to understand what's happening and I cannot help. I would only suggest to try running the code line by line pressing `F8` and move the cursor over all variables, cell values etc. and see what's happening...

Comment: I copied my dates (from B1) and numbers (from B2) to a new file and I managed to make it work for the first row (A2) - can't seem to make it work till the last row though
    Dim lr, lc1 As Long
    Dim sum As Long
    lr = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lc1 = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
  
    Set dates = WS.Range("B1", WS.Cells(1, lc1))
    For i = WS.Range("B1").Column To lc1
       If dates.Cells(1, i).Value <= till Then
          sum = sum + dates.Cells(2, i).Value
        Range("A2").Value = sum
       Else
          Exit For
       End If

Comment: I have tried the same thing on my file but it doesn't do anythinh. Can't understand. I have the data in a table - not sure if the issues come from the fact that the dates are the headers.

Comment: @V F I am not sure I can get you... Are the date you need in the range Q1 -> last column in the first row and formatted as `Date`? If so, I cannot help without seeing your workbook. It should work even if the data in discussion is part of a table. It can be also handed in a different way, but the above code should also work.

Comment: I sent you an email. thank you again

Comment: OK. I will look at it in some minutes...

Comment: @V F Please, test the updated answer and send some feedback. If it answers your question, we here vote the code up (if more the 15 notoriety) and more important, we tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the code works.